# Python Logging - only show logs from my libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have a relatively complex ecosystem of applications and libraries that are scheduled to run in my environment.

I am trying to improve my logging and in particular I'd like to write debug information to a logging file, and I'd like that log to contain the `logger.debug("string")`  lines from all the imported libraries I wrote, but not from libraries I import from pypi.

example:

```
import sys
import numpy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import logging

import mylibrary
import myotherlibrary

logger = logging.getLogger(application_name) # I don't use _ _ name _ _ in all of them, but I can change this line as necessary
```

so in this case when I set logger level to debug, I'd like to see debug information from the current script, from `mylibrary` and from `myotherlibrary` , but not from `bs4`,`numpy`, etc.

bonus: Ideally I would like to not have to hardcode every time the name of the libraries, but just have the script "know" it (from naming convention maybe?)

If anyone has any ideas it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you define your logger in your main script and in your other libraries?

Comment: logger = logging.getLogger(application_name)
# I don't use _ _ name _ _ in all of them, but I can change that

Comment: Are the libraries you wrote located in the same directory (ish) as the script you are calling, or are they installed (with pip etc)?

Comment: How does you environment run the python code? Is it running in a terminal and printing to a terminal like stdout? How do you configure your log display at your application's top level? Wherever this log level configuration happens you should set the log level of your root logger to something like WARNING or ERROR, but then set the log level of `application_name` to DEBUG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Python` doesn't really have a concept of "libraries I wrote" vs "libraries imported with pypi" - a library is a library unfortunately.

However, depending on how your libraries are set up, you *may* be able to get a *realllly hacky* custom logger?

By default, `Python` libraries installed with `pip` go to a central location - usually something like `/usr/local/lib` or `%APPDATA%` on windows. In contrast, local libraries are usually within the same directory as the calling script. We can use this to our advantage!

The following code demonstrates a kinda proof-of-concept - I've left a few methods needing implementing as an exercise ;)

```
#CustomLogger.py
import __main__
import logging
import os

#create a custom log class, inheriting the current logger class
class CustomLogger(logging.getLoggerClass()):
    custom_lib = False
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        #initialise the base logger
        super().__init__(name)

        #get the directory we are being run from
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(__main__.__file__)
        permutations = ['/', '.py', '.pyc']

        #check if we are a custom library, or if we are one installed via pip etc
        self.custom_lib = self.checkExists(current_dir, permutations)
        self.propagate = not self.custom_lib

    def checkExists(self, current_dir, permutations):
        #loop through each permutation and see if a file matching that spec exists
        #currently looks for .py/.pyc files and directories
        for perm in permutations:
            file = os.path.join(current_dir, self.name + perm)

            if os.path.exists(file):
                return True

        return False

    def isEnabledFor(self, level):
        if self.custom_lib:
            return super().isEnabledFor(level)

        return False

    #the hackiest part :)
    #these are two sample overrides that only log if we're a custom
    #library (i.e. one we've written, not installed)
    #there are a few more methods that I've not implemented, a full
    #list is available at https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger
    
    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.custom_lib:
            return super().debug(msg, args, kwargs)

    def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.custom_lib:
            return super().info(msg, args, kwargs)

#most important part - also override the logger class
#this means that any calls to logging.getLogger() will use our new subclass
logging.setLoggerClass(CustomLogger)
```

You could then use it like this:

```
import CustomLogger #needs importing first so it ensures the logger is setup

import sys
import numpy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import logging

import mylibrary
import myotherlibrary

logger = logging.getLogger(application_name) #returns type CustomLogger
```